# Custom comparator in lower_bound() STL

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to understand how comparators work in lower_bound functions and I came across this example:

```
#include <vector>  
#include <algorithm>  

using namespace std;  

bool ignore_case(char a, char b) {  
   return(tolower(a) == tolower(b));  
}  

int main(void) {  
   vector<char> v = {'A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'E'};  
   auto it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'C');  

   cout << "First element which is greater than \'C\' is " << *it << endl;  

   it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'C', ignore_case);  

   cout << "First element which is greater than \'C\' is " << *it << endl;  

   it = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 'z', ignore_case);  

   cout << "All elements are less than \'z\'." << endl;  

   return 0;  
}
```

The output of the following code is:

```
First element which is greater than 'C' is b
First element which is greater than 'C' is d
All elements are less than 'z'.
```

How does the custom comparator of equality check work ?. I thought it returned true if a should be before b and false if vice versa. How does it work in lower_bound() functions where it is supposed to retrieve the FIRST value that is greater than equal to our given key.

Comment: Read again and also tests with some value pairs in both (!) orders.

Comment: I'm trying to figure how the comparator fits in the lower_bound(), checked a lot of resources, if the lower_bound() returns the first value , shouldn't it return a here as it is != our key ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound -- just read that and compare that with your function.

Answer (score 2):

This example doesn't use `std::lower_bound` correctly. If `comp` is the comparator used and `value` is the value searched for, all elements for which `comp(element, value) == true` must be before all elements for which `comp(element, value) == false` in the range. This is not the case in any of the calls shown.

In addition, the comparator is supposed to return true if the first argument is less than the second argument, while the function shown returns true if the first element is equal to the second argument. This on its own isn't strictly forbidden but it likely won't produce the expected results.

Comment: If I use a comparator function such as 

```bool compare(int a, int b) {
 return a <= b;
}``` it returns the LAST value that is less than equal to my given key, shouldn't the lower_bound give me the first value ? The array I use it on is sorted

Comment: @shawnindamnen, with this comparator, `std::lower_bound` turns into `std::upper_bound`. It doesn't return the last value that is `<=`, but first that is `>`.

Comment: Is there any way to intuitively understand how the comparator works in finding out the value from the given array ?

Comment: @shawnindamnen, a comparator partitions the range, and `lower_bound` finds the first element for which a comparator returns `false`. `lower_bound` uses binary search, so the partition requirement is important.

Comment: @shawnindamnen The range isn't sorted by your comparator, so your call is incorrect. `std::lower_bound` returns the first value which compares false with the given value, **with the assumption that all values which compare true are before all values which compare false**.

Comment: so in the above case where we are using the == operator, shouldn't it return the first value that is not equal to our key i.e. a ?

Comment: @shawnindamnen, in that case you violate the requirements of `std::lower_bound`, the behaviour is undefined. Like trying to evaluate `1 / 0`. `std::lower_bound` only works for a partitioned range. If it is not partitioned, use linear search `std::find`.

Comment: @shawnindamnen If you use `==` as comparator, then your range need to be partitioned with respect to this comparator. Therefore, first (on the left) there must be elements that satisfy `==` and then (on the right) those that doesn't. Your `v` does not meet this condition. If `v` was `{'c','C','a','B','e'}`, then the call with `ignore` and `C` would be fine.